# Simple profiling for Fortran+openMP?

Tags: fortran, profiling, openmp, hpc

I have been using `gprof` to benchmark a code but since I started parallelizing it I realize that `gprof` doesn't give useful output.

How do I profile or do something that can help find the bottlenecks?

I've heard of `Scalasca` and `TAU` but they seem a bit overkill.

Comment: Please let me remark, that easy-to-use and free are somewhat contrary in this context. Free HPC tools are built by researchers with a focus on techniques and features. Basically you don't get a research grant for making a tool easy to use. Commercial tools can be more focused towards usability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest to use tool is [`perf`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page). It can easily [be installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50145/how-to-install-perf-monitoring-tool) on any Linux system and works fairly well with OpenMP or other threaded applications.

You can look at live performance simply by running `sudo perf top` on your command line. This will tell you the functions and source code lines that are currently consuming the most CPU resources like `top` does for whole processes.

Prefixing your application with:

```
perf record ./your-program your-parameter
perf report
```

Will present a profile on a function and source code line basis. There are many parameters to tune `perf`, e.g. by enabling call graph tracing with `-g`.

However, while threads are supported you cannot easily distinguish them. So you won't know which thread showed what performance characteristics. For that you should resort to more specialized HPC tools, even if they *seem a bit overkill*. You have to consider that analyzing parallel performance is not simple. No matter what tool you use.

Free tools would be:

- [HPCToolkit](http://hpctoolkit.org/): the simplest to use, because it uses sampling only, so there is no need to recompile your application
- [Score-P](http://www.vi-hps.org/projects/score-p/) for recording and [Cube](http://www.scalasca.org/software/cube-4.x) for analysis of profiles (the sites seem to be down temporaily)
- [Tau](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/home.php)

Comment: `perf` is exactly what I was looking for here. On Ubuntu 16 I need `sudo` before most command. `perf annotate` seems useful too. Thanks a lot @Zulan!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Intel commercial software there are a couple of very useful tools. With [Intel Vtune amplifier](https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-vtune) you can examine the hotspots for a serial run as well as the effective usage of your cores (in the image a summary graph for a 24 cores openMP run)[image]